# Parse data from input string

Tags: c, parsing

I'm having this kind of input data.

`<html>...... 
<!-- OK -->`

I only want to extract the data before the comment sign `<!--`.
This is my code:

```
char *parse_data(char *input) {
    char *parsed_data = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char));
    sscanf(input, "%s<!--%*s", parsed_data);
    return parsed_data;
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to return the expected result. I can't figure out why is that so.

Could anyone explain me the proper way to extract this kind of data and the behavior of 'sscanf()`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"%s"` format specifier will not treat `"<!--"` as a single delimiter, or any of the individual characters as a delimiter (which would not be the correct behaviour anyway). Only whitespace is considered a delimiter. Scan sets are available in `sscanf()` but they take a collection of individual characters rather that a sequence of characters representing a single delimiter. This means that everything in `input` before the first whitespace character will be assigned to `parsed_data`.

You could use `strstr()` instead:

```
const char* comment_start = strstr(input, "<!--");
char* result = 0;
if (comment_start)
{
    result = malloc(comment_start - input + 1);
    memcpy(result, input, comment_start - input);
    result[comment_start - input] = 0;
}
```

Note that `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` so can be omitted as part of the `malloc()` argument calculation.